# Efficient way of loading minibatches < gpu memory

Tags: theano

I have the following scenario:

- My dataset >> gpu memory
- My minibatches < gpu memory ... such that depending on size I can fit up to 10 in memory at once while still training no problem.

The size of my dataset means I won't revisit datapoints, so I guess no point in making them shared?  Or is there?  I was thinking that maybe it would be beneficial to have up to 10 shared initialised variables of size=mini-batch, such that I can I swap 10 in at once instead of just one at a a time.  Also, is it possible to preload mini-batches in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not revisiting datapoints then there probably isn't any value in using shared variables.

The following code could be modified and used to evaluate the different methods of getting data into your specific computation.

The "input" method is the one that will probably be best when you have no need to revisit data. The "shared_all" method may outperform everything else but only if you can fit the entire dataset in GPU memory. The "shared_batched" allows you to evaluate whether hierarchically batching your data could help.

In the "shared_batched" method, the dataset is divided into many macro batches and each macro batch is divided into many micro batches. A single shared variable is used to hold a single macro batch. The code evaluates all the micro batches within the current macro batch. Once a complete macro batch has been processed the next macro batch is loaded into the shared variable and the code iterates over the micro batches within it again.

In general, it might be expected that small numbers of large memory transfers will operate faster than larger numbers of smaller transfers (where the total transfered is the same for each). But this needs to be tested (e.g. with the code below) before it can be known for sure; YMMV.

The use of the "borrow" parameter may also have a significant impact on the performance, but be aware of [the implications](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/aliasing.html) before using it.

```
import math
import timeit
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt


def test_input(data, batch_size):
    assert data.shape[0] % batch_size == 0
    batch_count = data.shape[0] / batch_size
    x = tt.tensor4()
    f = theano.function([x], outputs=x.sum())
    total = 0.
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for batch_index in xrange(batch_count):
        total += f(data[batch_index * batch_size: (batch_index + 1) * batch_size])
    print 'IN\tNA\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (batch_size, batch_size, timeit.default_timer() - start, total)


def test_shared_all(data, batch_size):
    batch_count = data.shape[0] / batch_size
    for borrow in (True, False):
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        all = theano.shared(data, borrow=borrow)
        load_time = timeit.default_timer() - start
        x = tt.tensor4()
        i = tt.lscalar()
        f = theano.function([i], outputs=x.sum(), givens={x: all[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]})
        total = 0.
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        for batch_index in xrange(batch_count):
            total += f(batch_index)
        print 'SA\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (
            borrow, batch_size, batch_size, load_time + timeit.default_timer() - start, total)


def test_shared_batched(data, macro_batch_size, micro_batch_size):
    assert data.shape[0] % macro_batch_size == 0
    assert macro_batch_size % micro_batch_size == 0
    macro_batch_count = data.shape[0] / macro_batch_size
    micro_batch_count = macro_batch_size / micro_batch_size
    macro_batch = theano.shared(numpy.empty((macro_batch_size,) + data.shape[1:], dtype=theano.config.floatX),
                                borrow=True)
    x = tt.tensor4()
    i = tt.lscalar()
    f = theano.function([i], outputs=x.sum(), givens={x: macro_batch[i * micro_batch_size:(i + 1) * micro_batch_size]})
    for borrow in (True, False):
        total = 0.
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        for macro_batch_index in xrange(macro_batch_count):
            macro_batch.set_value(
                data[macro_batch_index * macro_batch_size: (macro_batch_index + 1) * macro_batch_size], borrow=borrow)
            for micro_batch_index in xrange(micro_batch_count):
                total += f(micro_batch_index)
        print 'SB\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (
            borrow, macro_batch_size, micro_batch_size, timeit.default_timer() - start, total)


def main():
    numpy.random.seed(1)

    shape = (20000, 3, 32, 32)

    print 'Creating random data with shape', shape
    data = numpy.random.standard_normal(size=shape).astype(theano.config.floatX)

    print 'Running tests'
    for macro_batch_size in (shape[0] / pow(10, i) for i in xrange(int(math.log(shape[0], 10)))):
        test_shared_all(data, macro_batch_size)
        test_input(data, macro_batch_size)
        for micro_batch_size in (macro_batch_size / pow(10, i) for i in
                                 xrange(int(math.log(macro_batch_size, 10)) + 1)):
            test_shared_batched(data, macro_batch_size, micro_batch_size)


main()
```